# PHP: Issue with namespaces and files required exist in subfolder

Tags: php

This is my file tree:

```
/lib
  |- /external
    |- /Email
      |- /Mandrill
         |- Templates.php
         |- Exceptions.php
         |- // others files
      |- Mandrill.php
```

(with `Mandrill.php` under the folder "Email" and folder "Mandrill" under the folder "Email")

I'm using F3 Framework with his `autoload` function (http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#TheF3Autoloader)

This is my autoload:

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','app/controllers/|app/models/|app/services/|lib/external/');
```

This is `Mandrill.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Email;

require_once 'Mandrill/Templates.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Exports.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Users.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Rejects.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Inbound.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Tags.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Messages.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Whitelists.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Ips.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Internal.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Subaccounts.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Urls.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Webhooks.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Senders.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Metadata.php';
require_once 'Mandrill/Exceptions.php';

class Mandrill {
 // stuff
}
```

And I can start Mandrill **without** problem ( `$mandrill = New \Email\Mandrill();`)

In `Templates.php` I have

```
<?php
namespace Email\Mandrill;

class Mandrill_Templates {
    public function __construct(Mandrill $master) {
        $this->master = $master;
    }
```

But error is `Fatal error: Class 'Email\Mandrill_Templates' not found`

If I move `Templates.php` at same level of `Mandrill.php`, changing path of require, error "move" to Exports.php and so on.

So, question is: how use namespace(s) right? Thank you!